# Vue.js componet does not appear on a web page

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a Laravel project using vue js.
I made a toggle component with Vue.js to display and hide an element.
But the toggle button does not appear in my page.
What's wrong with my code ? I can find only Hello component appear on the page.

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import Hello from './components/Hello.vue';
import Toggle from './components/Toggle.vue';

createApp({
    components: {
        Hello,
        Toggle,
    }
}).mount('#app');
```

Toggle.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button @click="toggleVisibility">Toggle</button>
        <div v-if="visible">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Toggle',
    data() {
        return {
            visible: true
        };
    },
    methods: {
        toggleVisibility() {
            this.visible = !this.visible;
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Hello.vue

```
<template>
    <h1>{{message}}</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Hello',
    data() {
        return {
            message: 'Hello world'
        };
    }
};
</script>
```

welcome.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Laravel</title>
</head>
<body class="antialiased">
<div id="app">
    <Hello/>
    <Toggle>
        <p>This will be appeared</p>
    </Toggle>
</div>
</body>
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: What laravel version are you using? Do you have a `vite` file? or just `mix`? Check the browser console and see if you have any errors in there

Comment: Your code should work fine. Looks like there is any minor dependency injection issue. Please cross check the communication of the components and try to find the root cause by debugging it.